# notification run in the screen lock

Tags: android, reactjs, flutter, dart

[look there this is the notification running in the background and if i press on this notification it will direct navigate me to a specific screen in the app without unlocking the device so i need to make the same idea but i am using flutter so anyone here could help please](https://i.stack.imgur.com/rd13B.jpg)

i have searched for flutter local notification and local auth and many other packages but i still stucked there and do not know what i have to do or what is the right choice to make this feature .